# How to Customize PushNotificaionIOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, push-notification

I'm using PushNotificationIOS for receiving remote notifications for IOS.

```
PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('notification', (notifIOS) => {}
```

Requirement: I want to display a specific message for different types of notifications i receive remotely.

Result : When ever i receive a remote notification, a local notification is automatically triggered and displays the message i get from 'notifIOS'.

I dont want the local notifications to be triggered automatically instead, i would like to call

```
PushNotificationIOS.presentLocalNotification({alertBody:"body",category : "type"});
```

everytime i receive a remote notification.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom plugin and pass your push data to native view controller then handle it using the extension.

create an extension of notification that is  "Notification Content Extension". follow some tutorials or apple official developer document [Customizing Push notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH16-SW1)